# Action.payload passed to worker Saga became undefined during code process

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, saga

After passing an `action.payload` from component to workerSag it's making undefined during the action process by some reason. Below you can find excerpts of my code.

Action from component:

```
const showQueryOnMapHandler = (event) => {
  const chosenQueryId = +event.currentTarget.id;
  dispatch(mapActions.setCoordinates({ chosenQueryId, queries }));
};
```

Saga:

```
const getQueryCoordinates = (action) => {
  console.log(action.payload.queries);
  console.log(action.payload.chosenQueryId);

  const queryIndex = action.payload.queries.findIndex(
    (element) => element.queryId === action.payload.chosenQueryId
  );

  const coordinatesFromTo = {
    newFromLat: action.payload.queries[queryIndex].coordinatesFrom.lat,
    newFromLng: action.payload.queries[queryIndex].coordinatesFrom.lng,
    newToLat: action.payload.queries[queryIndex].coordinatesTo.lat,
    newToLng: action.payload.queries[queryIndex].coordinatesTo.lng,
  };
  return coordinatesFromTo;
};

function* workerQueryClickSaga(action) {
  yield put(queriesActions.choseQuery(action.payload.chosenQueryId));
  yield put(mapActions.setCoordinates(getQueryCoordinates(action)));
  yield put(mapActions.setBounds());
}

function* watchQueryClickSaga() {
  yield takeEvery("map/setCoordinates", workerQueryClickSaga);
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield fork(watchQueryClickSaga);
}

export default rootSaga;
```

Redux:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import mapSlice from "./reducers/map-slice";
import queriesSlice from "./reducers/queries-slice";
import rootSaga from "./sagas";

const saga = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { queries: queriesSlice.reducer, map: mapSlice.reducer },
  middleware: [saga],
});

saga.run(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

Map-slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const mapSlice = createSlice({
  name: "map",
  initialState: {
    fromLat: null,
    fromLng: null,
    toLat: null,
    toLng: null,
    bounds: null,
    fetchedPolyline: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setCoordinates(state, action) {
      state.fromLat = action.payload.fromLat;
      state.fromLng = action.payload.fromLng;
      state.toLat = action.payload.toLat;
      state.toLng = action.payload.toLng;
    },
    setBounds(state) {
      state.bounds = [
        [state.fromLat, state.fromLng],
        [state.toLat, state.toLng],
      ];
    },
  },
});

export const mapActions = mapSlice.actions;

export default mapSlice;
```

Queries-Slice:

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const mapSlice = createSlice({
  name: "map",
  initialState: {
    fromLat: null,
    fromLng: null,
    toLat: null,
    toLng: null,
    bounds: null,
    fetchedPolyline: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    setCoordinates(state, action) {
      state.fromLat = action.payload.fromLat;
      state.fromLng = action.payload.fromLng;
      state.toLat = action.payload.toLat;
      state.toLng = action.payload.toLng;
    },
    setBounds(state) {
      state.bounds = [
        [state.fromLat, state.fromLng],
        [state.toLat, state.toLng],
      ];
    },
  },
});

export const mapActions = mapSlice.actions;

export default mapSlice;
```

[Here is consol.log() results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p94h.png)

I tried to put `getQueryCoordinates` function body to `workerQueryClickSaga` but nothing changed unfortunately.

Comment: The actions, reducers, and saga middleware don't make sense. The `mapSlice` action creators expect payload objects with `fromLat`, `fromLng`, `toLat`, and `toLng` properties, but the action is dispatched with `chosenQueryId` and `queries` properties. The error isn't that *some* action's payload is undefined, it is that `action.payload.queries` is undefined when attempting to access the `findIndex` property. It seems there's a mismatch somewhere in your code. Can you [edit] the post to hopefully provide better context?

Comment: Dear Drew,
thank you for the interest to my question. Actually i have already solved this problem. ( Just got my hands to reply only now =( ).

There was a loop, because i have waching for "map/setCoordinates" in the takeEvery, and calling setCoordinates in put method.

Solution:
Dispatch an action from the component with unic type which is not secified in mapSlice.

I hope you'll understand me =)